# Apache kafka sending java object failed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have this object

```
       HashMap message = new HashMap();
       message.put("x", "xxxxx");
       message.put("y", "yyyyy");
       message.put("z", 100);

       ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord(topic, message);
       producer.send(producerRecord);
```

I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.util.HashMap to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide Kafka with a way how to convert you messages, in this case `HashMap`, into binary form. From the [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html):

> The key.serializer and value.serializer instruct how to turn the key and value objects the user provides with their ProducerRecord into bytes. You can use the included ByteArraySerializer or StringSerializer for simple string or byte types.

The example of usage:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("key.serializer", "YourImplementation");
 props.put("value.serializer", "YourImplementation");

 Producer<String, HashMap> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
```

Comment: a simple example will be nice

Comment: I get the error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class java.util.HashMap to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Hashmap into json and use JsonSerializer as

```
private void configureProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.serializer", JsonSerializer.class.getName());
    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
}
```

Or You can also use ByteArraySerializer. Refer [this](http://www.bigendiandata.com/2016-08-14-How-to-use-Java-Serializers-with-Kafka/)